# Exchange 2016 returning 550 5.7.1 when sending to our domain using 3rd party email sender sending on behalf of our domain

Tags: spf, exchange-2016

We have an on-premise Exchange 2016 server. Mail flow is normal. However, recently we started using a 3rd party email service to send out our newsletters (Klaviyo). When we send out campaigns our Exchange server is rejecting the emails that are being sent to our own domain. This is what I see in our Exchange logs.

```
{[{LED=550 5.7.1 Send ID (PRA) Not permitted};{MSG=};{FQDN=};{IP=192.xxx.xxx.xxx};{LRT=}]}
```

I have an SPF record set up, however, Kalviyo uses dynamic IPs and I can't add them to the SPF record. They are sending from send.ourdomain.com. It's possible my SPF record is incorrect.

```
v=spf1 ip4:xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx ip4:xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx include:servers.mcsv.net -all include:send.ourdomain.com -all
```

I didn't set up the Exchange server, so I don't know if the issue is with an Exchange setting, or with our SPF record.

Where are all the places I need to look that would be able to create this reject error so I can resolve this issue?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If your SPF record is indeed the following:

```
v=spf1 ip4:xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx ip4:xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx include:servers.mcsv.net -all include:send.ourdomain.com -all
```

Then it is malformed. The **-all** should only be at the end. You have it in the middle and at the end. If you provide your actual domain name we can look up your SPF record to verify that it's malformed or if that was just a typo in your question.

Comment: Here is the domain name: murphysmagic.com. I hope what you mentioned is the only problem. I won't change it until you can verify the SPF record. Thank you in advance for your help.

Comment: Your SPF record is definitely malformed. The syntax is incorrect. You need to remove the **-all** from the middle. - https://mxtoolbox.com/SuperTool.aspx?action=spf%3amurphysmagic.com&run=toolpage

Comment: Fantastic! I remove the **-all** from the middle of the SPF record leaving only the **-all** at the very end. Things seem to be working now!! Thank you for your assistance. That was a very simple fix!

Comment: Glad to help...